# Finding period of a function

Tags: calculus

> I am trying to find period of $$f(x)= \sin x + \{x\},$$ 
>   where $\{x\}$ is fractional part of $x$.

**My approach:**

Suppose the period is $L$ then it should satisfy 
$f(x+L)= f(x)$ it means $$\sin(x+L)+\{x+L\} =\sin x+ \{x\}$$
it may be further reduced to 
$$\sin x \cos L- \cos x \sin L= \sin x + \{x\}$$

Kindly suggest how to proceed further to find the value of $L$.

Comment: Perhaps you should begin from identifying the periods of the summands, $\sin x$ and $\{x\}$.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this function is not periodic. I would guess that if $g$ and $h$ are periodic and their periods have no common integral multiple, then $g+h$ is not periodic.

Comment: @MPW that's good enough for an answer.

Comment: in the last step where did $\{x+L\}$ disappear?

Comment: Can you see that $\sin(x)+\sin(x\sqrt{2})$ is not a periodic function, for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ has period $L$, so does $f(x+1)-f(x)=2\,\sin\frac{1}{2}\,\cos(x+\frac{1}{2})$. So we would have $L=2\,k\,\pi$, but that's not a period, because $f(2\,k\,\pi)=\{2\,k\,\pi\}\neq f(0)=0$ for $k\neq0$, since $\pi$ is irrational.
The unproven claim concerning the period of a sum of periodic functions is true only under some regularity conditions for $g$ and $h$ (for instance continuity, but $\{x\}$ is not continuous), not in general, and even that isn't trivial to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Such $L$ does not exist ! Assume to the contrary, that such $L$ exists.

With $x=0$ we get:

$\sin(L)=-\{L\}$

and with $x= \pi /2$ we get:

$\cos(L)=1+\{\pi /2\}$.

Hence

$1=\cos^2(L)+\sin^2(L)=(1+\{\pi /2\})^2+\{L\}^2>1$,

a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks ! got it

Comment: I don't see how you got the equation $\cos(L)=1+\{\pi/2\}$.

Comment: It's wrong, the correct equation should be $\cos L +\{L+\pi/2\}=1+\{\pi/2\}$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, ah yes, it looks like it came from an incorrect formula in the OP.